# Visual Studio - ASP.NET Core - Problems when I add a new class

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanted to integrate a Microsoft Sign-In functionality into my ASP.NET core site. When reading following section in the Microsoft Docs, they suggest to download a preconfigured project which has a bit of configuration done for you.
Link: [Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

Everything works fine. The project was setup for .netcore 2 but I upgraded it to .net5. When I wanted to create a new class it just creates the class and the namespace but in a weird formatted way. It only happens with this project. Now I already did all the things that you would try. Clean Code, Rebuild Solution, Repairing Visual Studio. Nothing changed.

Heres a picture:

[image]

When going over the red lines it points me to CS0116:A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.

Does someone know whats going on here or am I just blind?

Comment: Dashes are not allowed in namespaces

Comment: Thanks that was the problem there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces cannot contain dash characters `-`

The reason the error says

> CS0116:A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.

Is because of the dashes `-`, it thinks you are trying to perform a mathematical operation and subtract a variable or object named `OpenIDConnect` from `namespace WebApp`, which is not allowed.

You could instead:

1. Use a period `.` if these are meant to be nested namespaces
2. Use underscores `_`
3. TitleCase your namespaces by just removing the dashes

Comment: Thanks that was it. I changed the name to something else. Kinda weird that this is a project on the ms docs that has an error but yea seems like an older project or so